# Deserializing a list of objects creates a new object for an empty node .NET

Tags: c#, json, .net

I have this JSON that's a list of objects, like this.

```
"Fields": [
    {
        "fieldID": 1,
        "name": "field"
    }
]
```

When the list is empty, it is sent like this

```
"Fields": [
    {}
]
```

I read this in as a string and then try to deserialize it using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);` where T is the object that matches the field model. When I do this though, I get a new list with one item in it (count = 1 when it should be 0), the same as if I deserialized this JSON.

```
"Fields": [
    {
        "fieldID": 0,
        "name": null
    }
]
```

How can I avoid or work around this?

Comment: What prevents  you from checking  if(Fields[0].name==null)  Fields=null; ?

Comment: Just extra work that I feel should be caught by the serializer, inherently or through the settings.

Comment: If this too much work for you, you can create a custom serializer then

Comment: _'When the list is empty, it is sent like this' `"Fields": [ {} ]`_. It is not an empty list. **It's a list with one element**. The empty list will look like `"Fields": [ ]`. The problem is in JSON, not in `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method.  If you cannot fix JSON, then  simply check properties of the first element and remove it when properties have default values.

Answer (score 0):

First following json does not represent empty list:

```
"Fields": [
    {}
]
```

An empty list in json should look like following:

```
"Fields": []
```

So you should try to fix the json. However, if that's proven to be impossible you can do something like following:

```
        using (JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString))
        {
            JsonElement root = document.RootElement;
            var l = root.EnumerateArray().First().ToString();
            if(l=="{}")
            {
              //do something
            }
        }
```

What's happening is that you simply parsing the json and enumerate through the list of element and detect if "{}" exists.

Or, you can go with a more complex way which is writing a custom converter which handles such case in the way you want. You can check out the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1)